# SharePoint hide spfieldurl column description(Type of description)

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, field

I am trying not to have the column description for field type "URL" in SharePoint 2016. I want to use this OOTB column URL, but not get "Type the description". The only work around i saw is using JavaScript. I wanted to know, is there any other way remove it?
Programmatically, or some property in schema.xml?

Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Menon

Answer (score 1):

Sample JSlink script for you.

You could upload jQuery library and the custom jslink library to SharePoint library, I upload to layouts folder just for easy testing.

script:

```
(function () {

    var JSHyperlinkFieldCtx = {};
    JSHyperlinkFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    JSHyperlinkFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "JSHyperlink": {
            "NewForm": HideJSHyperlinkTemplate
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(JSHyperlinkFieldCtx);
})();

function HideJSHyperlinkTemplate(ctx) {

    var result = SPFieldUrl_Edit(ctx);   
    var $f = $(result);
    $f.find('span:eq(1)').css('display', 'none');
    $f.find('input:eq(1)').css('display', 'none');
    return $f.html();
}
```

use the script:

```
~sitecollection/_layouts/15/jslinks/jquery-1.12.4.js|~sitecollection/_layouts/15/jslinks/HyperlinkField.js
```

[image]